# I have a question about the AWS Selling Partner API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

first of all, I apologize if my question seems awkward as English is not my native language. I am interested in using the AWS Selling Partner API (SP-API) and have a few questions:

**1. Is there a cost associated with using the API? If there is a cost, is there any traffic limitation?**

**2. Where can I find the documentation related to the costs?**

I tried to find information related to costs on the following site, but I couldn't find the information I was looking for. Can you help?

[https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/](https://stackoverflow.com)